# Table in paracol

Tags: tables, tabularx, paracol

I made a latex template where I want to have 4 columns. In one of the columns, I tried to make a table with three columns. But there is quit a bit wrong with my code. Could you help me?

```
% page setup
\documentclass[]{article}
\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% geometry
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\geometry{headsep=\baselineskip}

% colums / paragraphs
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{parskip} 

% table
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\small\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newgeometry{top=0.55in,bottom=0.55in,right=0.3in,left=0.3in} 
\begin{paracol}{4}

\begin{table}[h]
\settowidth\colwidth{hellohe} 
\begin{tabularx}{0.3\textwidth}{@{} P{\colwidth} *{2}{C} @{}}
\toprule
Lane
    & 1 & 2 \\
\addlinespace
Sample  
     & P4 & P3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have not defined `\colwidth`. Try to add `\newlength\colwidth`. I would set it before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: amazing! thank you very much!

Comment: do you know... can I set the \textwidth to the length of the column?

Comment: I think you are looking for `\linewidth`. While `\textwidth` is the width of the text on the page, `\linewidth` can be seen as the width of the current line, in your case the column. Normally theer is also something like `\columnwidth` but I don't know how that is with `paracol`.

Comment: You can overlap columns with paracol, but you should use \rlap, \llap, \makebox[columnwidth] or negative \hspace to avoid overfull hbox warnings.

Comment: Consider accepting the provided answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you are doing it this way, but this shows how to overlap columns.  It would be better to stop paracol and change the column widths.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% geometry
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\geometry{headsep=\baselineskip}

% colums / paragraphs
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{parskip} 

% table
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\small\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newlength{\colwidth}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newgeometry{top=0.55in,bottom=0.55in,right=0.3in,left=0.3in} 
\begin{paracol}{4}

\begin{table}[h]
\settowidth\colwidth{hellohe} 
\rlap{\begin{tabularx}{0.3\textwidth}{@{} P{\colwidth} *{2}{C} @{}}
\toprule
Lane
    & 1 & 2 \\
\addlinespace
Sample  
     & P4 & P3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}}
\end{table}
\switchcolumn
\noindent second column
\switchcolumn
\noindent third column
\switchcolumn
\noindent fourth column
\switchcolumn[0]*
\noindent continue from here
\switchcolumn
\noindent second column
\switchcolumn
\noindent third column
\switchcolumn
\noindent fourth column
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```